Capitalization of kinship term when used as a title
Would you capitalize a kinship term when it appears right before a proper name?
Example: Congratulazioni a Bisnonni Aldo e Maria Marini! or  Congratulazioni ai bisnonni Aldo e Maria Marini!

There is no reason at all to capitalise those terms. So: “Congratulazioni ai bisnonni Aldo e Maria...”
The only situation in which a kinship term might be written with a capital initial in Italian is if it forms, together with a name, a sort of whole proper noun, as in Zio Sam (Uncle Sam) or Babbo Natale (Father Christmas).
